# Adding a new multilingual domain site to google webmaster tools

Tags: seo, subdomain, multilingual

I am trying to add a new website with multilingual domain to a google webmaster tools.

Domain map is following:

```
www.domain.com (stands for english version)
it.domain.com
de.domain.com
es.domain.com
...
14 languages totally
```

Each webpage has links to itself in other languages.

I ask this questions because I couldn't find exact answer even at webmaster tools manuals. (Please refer if there any)

My question is: Should I add each sub-domain to webmaster tools or `www.domain.com` or just `domain.com`? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This document explains it a little.  It doesn't explicity state whether or not you should add each subdomain, but I think that depends on your content and how it's generated.

https://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=182192#1

I think if it were me I would add them as separate sites so you could do some geotargeting down the road (some more info from [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=34592))

Comment: Yep, that's right, manual mentioned about geotargeting for xx.domains.com that is only available in case of adding them separately.